# In Matplotlib, how do you add an Imagedraw object to a PyPlot?

Tags: image, matplotlib

I need to add a shape to a preexisting image generated using a pyplot (plt). The best way I know of to generate basic shapes quickly is using Imagedraw's predefined shapes. The original data has points with corresponding colors in line_holder and colorholder. I need to add a bounding box (or in this case ellipse) to the plot to make it obvious to the user whether the data is in an acceptable range.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.collections import LineCollection
from PIL import Image
...
lines = LineCollection(mpl.line_holder, colors=mpl.colorholder , linestyle='solid')
plt.axes().add_collection(lines)
plt.axes().set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
plt.axes().autoscale_view(True,True,True)
plt.draw()
plt.show()
```

I tried inserting this before the show():

```
image = Image.new('1',(int(ceil(disc/conv))+2,int(ceil(disc/conv))+1), 1)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(image)
box=(1, 1, int(ceil(disc/conv)), int(ceil(disc/conv))) #create bounding box
draw.ellipse(box, 1, 0) #draw circle in black
```

but I cannot find a way to then add this ellipse to the pyplot. Does anyone know how one would go about getting the images together? If it is not possible to add an imagedraw object to a pyplot, are there good alternatives for performing this type of operation?

Comment: Can you post your imports? It would be nice to see where everything is coming from.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Matplotlib has several patches (shapes) that appear to meet your needs (and remove PIL as a dependency).  They are documented [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/api/artist_api.html?highlight=circle#matplotlib.patches.Circle).  A helpful example using shapes is [here](http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/examples/api/patch_collection.html).

To add an ellipse to a plot, you first create a Ellipse patch and then add that patch to the axes you're currently working on.  Beware that Circle's (or Ellipse's with equal minor radii) will appear elliptical if your aspect ratio is not equal.

In your snippet you call plt.axes() several times.  This is unnecessary, as it is just returning the current axes object.  I think it is clearer to keep the axes object and directly operate on it rather than repeatedly getting the same object via plt.axes().  As far as axes() is used in your snippet, gca() does the same thing.  The end of my script demonstrates this.

I've also replaced your add_collection() line by a plotting a single line.  These essentially do the same thing and allows my snippet to be executed as a standalone script.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl

# set up your axes object
ax = plt.axes()
ax.set_aspect('equal', 'datalim')
ax.autoscale_view(True, True, True)

# adding a LineCollection is equivalent to plotting a line
# this will run as a stand alone script
x = range(10)
plt.plot( x, x, 'x-')

# add and ellipse to the axes
c = mpl.patches.Ellipse( (5, 5), 1, 6, angle=45)
ax.add_patch(c)

# you can get the current axes a few ways
ax2 = plt.axes()
c2 = mpl.patches.Ellipse( (7, 7), 1, 6, angle=-45, color='green')
ax2.add_patch(c2)

ax3 = plt.gca()
c3 = mpl.patches.Ellipse( (0, 2), 3, 3, color='black')
ax3.add_patch(c3)

print id(ax), id(ax2), id(ax3)

plt.show()
```

Comment: plt is not pylab. My fault, I didn't include the imports above. I have now added them.

Comment: as far as axes(), draw() and plot() go, pylab and matplotlib.pyplot are the same.  i've updated my snippet to use mpl.pyplot just to be clearer.

Comment: This doesn't quite work as written. The patches need to be an optional feature that is added later. Using the above code as an example, show() is called right after plt.plot(), and the patches then need to be put on the plot that that generates if the user asks for them.

Comment: also the boundaries of the plot need to shift so that the patch is fully visible.

Comment: to modify a plot after it is rendered, you are going to need to add a callback function to do the modification (http://matplotlib.sourceforge.net/users/event_handling.html).  Don't forget to re-render with fig.canvas.draw()